# Azure App Configuration - Conditionally create feature flag using bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-app-configuration, azure-feature-manager

I plan to use the Feature Management functionality within Azure App Configuration service.

Using bicep I create the configuration store.

- Template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.appconfiguration/2021-10-01-preview/configurationstores?tabs=bicep.

Using bicep I add a feature flag.

- Template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.appconfiguration/2021-10-01-preview/configurationstores/keyvalues?tabs=bicep.

The value should be initially set to `false` and once available it's up to the business/ops to change the value to `true` in the Azure Portal.

So I'm looking for a way to conditionally create the feature flag in my bicep; create the feature flag if it not exists. When it already exists, the bicep should skip creation because it could otherwise overwrite/reset the flag value changed by the business/ops.

I found this issue on GitHub from which I conclude that bicep does not yet support this requirement: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4023

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do that unless you check manually if the `featureFlag` exists before running the deployment.
ARM templates (and Bicep) try to be idempotent so if you apply the same template multiple times it will reset any manual changes.

Here is a bicep file that creates a config store and feature flag:

```bicep
// main.bicep
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param configurationStoreName string
param featureFlagExists bool
param featureFlagName string

// Create the configuration store
resource configurationStore 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores@2021-10-01-preview' = {
  name: configurationStoreName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'free'
  }
  properties: {
    disableLocalAuth: false
    enablePurgeProtection: false
    encryption: {}
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 0
  }
}

// Only create the feature flag if not exists
resource featureFlag 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/keyValues@2021-10-01-preview' = if (!featureFlagExists) {
  name: '.appconfig.featureflag~2F${featureFlagName}'
  parent: configurationStore
  properties: {
    contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.ff+json;charset=utf-8'
    tags: {}
    value: '{"id": "${featureFlagName}", "description": "", "enabled": false, "conditions": {"client_filters":[]}}'
  }
}
```

And here is a sample powershell script that invoke it:

1. check if the config store exists
2. check if the feature flag exists
3. run the deployment

```
$resourceGroupName = "<resource group name>"
$configurationStoreName = "<config store name>"
$featureFlagName = "<feature flag name>"

# Check if the app configuration exists
$appConfigExists = (az appconfig list `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --query "[?name=='$configurationStoreName'].id" `
| ConvertFrom-Json).Length -gt 0

# Check if the feature flag exists
$featureFlagExists = $false
if ($appConfigExists) {
  $featureFlagExists = (az appconfig kv list `
      --name $configurationStoreName `
      --query "[?key=='.appconfig.featureflag/$featureFlagName'].key" `
  | ConvertFrom-Json).Length -gt 0
}

az deployment group create `
  --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
  --template-file .\main.bicep `
  --parameters `
  configurationStoreName=$configurationStoreName `
  featureFlagExists=$featureFlagExists `
  featureFlagName=$featureFlagName
```